# ANDROID: Getting width and Height from a surfaceview class to a no context class

Tags: android

My problem is that I'm trying to get the width an heigth of my surfaceView from a non context class and I can not instance my surfaceview class(no context argument to give)!! Any sugestion?

Answer (score 0):

Since SurfaceView is a View, you really should be able to access it in a scope with a Context.

It is not clear from your question if you are trying to access an already infalted SurfaceView, or trying to instantiate one.
Keep in mind, however, that inflating a SurfaceView can also be done using XML.
See this example:
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/surfaceview/android-surfaceview-example/

Comment: I'm new to this!! So question would be how I create an object from a surfaceView class (that is already inflated) whithout context argument? I have 2 getters method to get width and heigth that I can not reach. I hopwe it's clearer...

Comment: 12:45:28.405 2621 #2621 ERROR AndroidRuntime java.lang.StackOverflowError